# How to Save/Download a mp3 DataURL object using java script?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, html5-filesystem

I allow the user to select a `mp3` file from the local file System and then 
allow to download the same file. Its for learning purpose.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function() {
                document.querySelector('#musicFile').addEventListener('change', function(e){
                            var file = e.target.files[0];
                            console.log(e, file);
                            if(file.type.match('audio.*')) { // if its an audio file
                                var fReader = new FileReader();

                                fReader.onload = function(ev) {  //onload event

                                    var dataUrl  = ev.target.result;


                                    var downloadCon = document.querySelector('#download') 
                                    downloadCon.href = dataUrl;
                                };

                                fReader.readAsDataURL(file);  //start reading the file 
                            }
                        });
            }
        </script>
```

The HTML body:

```
<body>
<div class="controls">  
                <input type="file" id="musicFile">
                <a id='download'href='#' download='music.mp3' class='downloadLink'>
                    Download File
                    </a>
            </div>
</body>
```

When I click the `Download File`, nothing happens. Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use FileReader to do that. Simply, you need to create a URLObject and make the A tag to point to it. The code for that (tested under Chrome and Firefox for Linux):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        document.querySelector('#musicFile').addEventListener('change', function(e){
            var file = e.target.files[0];
            console.log(e, file);
            if(file.type.match('audio.*')) { // if its an audio file
                document.getElementById( 'download' ).href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            }
         });
    }
</script>
```

To be more specific at what I did in your code - I removed all the FileReader code and added

```
document.getElementById( 'download' ).href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
```

in it's place. I didn't touch your HTML.

Hope that helps.